# My If Else Statement VB.Net's weird behavior

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

I have this program that when I typed the same text on the form and to the other form will add one (+1) to the label of my last form..There were no errors but when I wrote the correct answers on the textboxes it just gave me a number 1 instead of 10. Please help me guys. Thanks in advance :)

here is my code:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    frm4 = New Form4()
    frm1 = New Form1()
    Dim Textbox1 As New TextBox
    Dim Label3 As New Label
    If Textbox1.Text = frm1.TextBox2.Text Then
        frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox2.Text = frm1.TextBox4.Text Then
            frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
            If TextBox3.Text = frm1.TextBox6.Text Then
                frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
                If TextBox4.Text = frm1.TextBox8.Text Then
                    frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
                    If TextBox5.Text = frm1.TextBox10.Text Then
                        frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
                        If TextBox6.Text = frm1.TextBox12.Text Then
                            frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
                            If TextBox7.Text = frm1.TextBox14.Text Then
                                frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
                                If TextBox8.Text = frm1.TextBox16.Text Then
                                    frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
                                    If TextBox9.Text = frm1.TextBox18.Text Then
                                        frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
                                        If TextBox10.Text = frm1.TextBox20.Text Then
                                            frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
                                        End If
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If






        End If
        frm4.Show()

    Else
        frm4.Label3.Text = frm4.Label3.Text

        frm4.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

Form 2 codes:

```
 Public Class Form2
Private frm1 As Form1 ' remove the new here because it creates a new instance of Form1'
Private frm3 As Form3

Public lbl As New Label ' not needed?'

Private Sub Form2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Controls.Add(lbl)

End Sub
Public Sub New(ByVal callerInstance As Form1)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm1 = callerInstance
End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' Dim Label21 As Label = New Label          ' this label is not needed'
    ' Dim Textbox1 As TextBox = New TextBox     ' this  textbox is not needed'

    ' Create a new instance of Form3, do not use the automatic Form3 instance
    ' automatically created by VB.NET 
    frm3 = New Form3()

    ' now you are referring to the caller instance of Form1 '
    ' where there is the textbox filled with your text '
    frm3.Label21.Text = frm1.TextBox1.Text
    frm3.Label22.Text = frm1.TextBox3.Text
    frm3.Label23.Text = frm1.TextBox5.Text
    frm3.Label24.Text = frm1.TextBox7.Text
    frm3.Label25.Text = frm1.TextBox9.Text
    frm3.Label26.Text = frm1.TextBox11.Text
    frm3.Label27.Text = frm1.TextBox13.Text
    frm3.Label28.Text = frm1.TextBox15.Text
    frm3.Label29.Text = frm1.TextBox17.Text
    frm3.Label30.Text = frm1.TextBox19.Text






    frm3.Show()

End Sub
End Class
```

Form1 Codes:

```
 Public Class Form1
Private frm2 As Form2

Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    If frm2 Is Nothing Then
        frm2 = New Form2(Me)
        AddHandler frm2.FormClosed, AddressOf Me.Form2HasBeenClosed

        Dim Label21 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label21.Text = TextBox1.Text
        frm2.Label21.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label22 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label22.Text = TextBox2.Text
        frm2.Label22.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label23 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label23.Text = TextBox3.Text
        frm2.Label23.ForeColor = Color.Black

        Dim Label24 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label24.Text = TextBox4.Text
        frm2.Label24.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label25 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label25.Text = TextBox5.Text
        frm2.Label25.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label26 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label26.Text = TextBox6.Text
        frm2.Label26.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label27 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label27.Text = TextBox7.Text
        frm2.Label27.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label28 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label28.Text = TextBox8.Text
        frm2.Label28.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label29 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label29.Text = TextBox9.Text
        frm2.Label29.ForeColor = Color.Black

        Dim Label30 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label30.Text = TextBox10.Text
        frm2.Label30.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label31 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label31.Text = TextBox11.Text
        frm2.Label31.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label32 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label32.Text = TextBox12.Text
        frm2.Label32.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label33 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label33.Text = TextBox13.Text
        frm2.Label33.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label34 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label34.Text = TextBox14.Text
        frm2.Label34.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label35 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label35.Text = TextBox15.Text
        frm2.Label35.ForeColor = Color.Black

        Dim Label36 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label36.Text = TextBox16.Text
        frm2.Label36.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label37 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label37.Text = TextBox17.Text
        frm2.Label37.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label38 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label38.Text = TextBox18.Text
        frm2.Label38.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label39 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label39.Text = TextBox19.Text
        frm2.Label39.ForeColor = Color.Black


        Dim Label40 As Label = New Label
        frm2.Label40.Text = TextBox20.Text
        frm2.Label40.ForeColor = Color.Black


    End If

    If frm2 IsNot Nothing Then
        frm2.Show(Me) 'Show Second Form  
        Me.Hide()
    End If

End Sub
Sub Form2HasBeenClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As FormClosedEventArgs)
    frm2 = Nothing
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

Form 3 Code:(instance calling to form1)

```
Public Class Form3
Private frm3 As Form3
Private frm1 As Form1
Private frm4 As Form4

Public Sub New1(ByVal callerInstance As Form1)

    ' Call required if you add your constructor manually
    InitializeComponent()

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor
    frm1 = callerInstance
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Text is not a number.  Adding 1 to text is, therefore, a meaningless operation.  I'm surprised it even compiles.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes it will compile as long as you put 0 or any number on the text property of a textbox or label :) Hi can you give an example of the elseif statement using my code? Thanks a lot

Comment: If you can treat the Text property as a number without any kind of conversion in VB, then I'm out of my league.

Comment: VB will automatically convert numeric string into int, long and so on...as long as it is a valid numeric. It is the nature of VB compiler.

Comment: @Jade It is also one of the evils of the VB compiler, that is why it is recommended to always turn Option Strict On.

Comment: It'd be helpful to name your controls properly and not use 10-level nested `if`s. This code is horrible.

Comment: @siride Good day! can you please give me an example sir? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you want show in label number of right answers then
    You need compare all user answers with right answers
    And count times when answers are same:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
frm4 = New Form4()
frm1 = New Form1()
Dim Textbox1 As New TextBox
Dim Label3 As New Label
Dim sameQnt As Int32 = 0

If Textbox1.Text = frm1.TextBox2.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox2.Text = frm1.TextBox4.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox3.Text = frm1.TextBox6.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox4.Text = frm1.TextBox8.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox5.Text = frm1.TextBox10.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox6.Text = frm1.TextBox12.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox7.Text = frm1.TextBox14.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox8.Text = frm1.TextBox16.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox9.Text = frm1.TextBox18.Text Then sameQnt += 1
If Textbox10.Text = frm1.TextBox20.Text Then sameQnt += 1

'Print reslut
frm4.Label3.Text = sameQnt.ToString()
frm4.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: closing of if statements (end if) and the else statement error.

Comment: hi sir it still has errors Error 2 'End If' must be preceded by a matching 'If'. and Error 1 'Else' must be preceded by a matching 'If' or 'ElseIf'.

Comment: I added your all code, you don't need to use `else` at all

Comment: This mean, that you have only one right answer(where comparing return true). Or you referenced not that label which showed in the form

Comment: sadly all the answers are correct but still it does not count it :(

Comment: Can you even debug your code and check if it goes through your `if` checking?

Comment: yes sir i can debug it and it runs well but it does not do  its function

Comment: Put break on the line `If Textbox1.Text = frm1.TextBox2.Text Then sameQnt += 1` and then line by line check values of textboxes is they are same what you expect to be

Comment: they are the same but it does not give the right result sir

Comment: if when debugging your results are ok. The form which you see is not the same instance where you write in your code...

Comment: right now sir your code works fine now but instead of 2 the result is 10

Comment: Check block of code with `if... Then sameQnt += 1` step by step and you can check all values on runtime...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my new answer

```
Public Class MainForm '<----Your main form class name

    Dim frm4 = New Form4()'<----declare it here
    Dim frm1 = New Form1()'<----declare it here

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim Textbox1 As New TextBox
        Dim Label3 As New Label

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        If Textbox1.Text = frm1.TextBox2.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox2.Text = frm1.TextBox4.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox3.Text = frm1.TextBox6.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox4.Text = frm1.TextBox8.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox5.Text = frm1.TextBox10.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox6.Text = frm1.TextBox12.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox7.Text = frm1.TextBox14.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox8.Text = frm1.TextBox16.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox9.Text = frm1.TextBox18.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1
        If TextBox10.Text = frm1.TextBox20.Text Then i += 1 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1

        frm4.Label3.Text = i.ToString()

        frm4.Show()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hi sir thanks for all your replies but I already declared it here on my form3 as Private..is there any possible solutions for this dilemma? The code runs well with just one statement but if it is a multiple statements it just get stuck with one :(

Comment: @netoriusboyboy, If you can post the full source then we can help.  The problem is in your design.