# Wrong Result to the last form on label always 0

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms

Hi good day guys i would just like to seek some help regarding my problem here in VB.NET. I have this program that if the text in the textbox is equal to the text in the textbox of the previous form it will add 1 for each correct answer but instead it always shows zero (0) (last form) and not showing the results that I want. Here is my code guys I hope you can help me with this problem thanks in advance.

```
Imports System.Convert 
Imports System.IO 
Public Class Form3 

Private frm1 As Form1 
Private frm4 As Form4 

Public Sub New1(ByVal callerInstance As Form1) 

    InitializeComponent() 

    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor 
    frm1 = callerInstance 
End Sub 

Public Sub New2(ByVal callerInstance As Form4) 

    InitializeComponent() 
    ' save the instance of the Me variable passed to this constructor 
    frm4 = callerInstance 
End Sub 

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Button1.Click 
    Dim frm1 As Form1 = Form1 
    Dim frm4 As Form4 = Form4 
    frm1 = New Form1 
    frm4 = New Form4 

    'program execution proper 
    Dim lbl3 As Integer = CInt(frm4.Label3.Text) 
    lbl3 = CInt(frm4.Label3.Text) 
    Dim Label22 As New Label 
    If frm1.TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text Then 
        lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 'if(integer.tryparse, lbl3) then lbl3 += 1 
        Dim Label24 As New Label 
        If Not frm1.TextBox4.Text = TextBox2.Text Then 
            lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 
            Dim Label26 As New Label 
            If Not frm1.TextBox6.Text = TextBox3.Text Then 
                lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 
                Dim Label28 As New Label 
                If Not frm1.TextBox8.Text = TextBox4.Text Then 
                    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 
                    Dim Label30 As New Label 
                    If Not frm1.TextBox10.Text = TextBox5.Text Then 
                        lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 
                        Dim Label32 As New Label 
                        If Not frm1.TextBox12.Text = TextBox6.Text Then 
                            lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 
                            Dim Label34 As New Label 
                            If Not frm1.TextBox14.Text = TextBox7.Text Then 
                                lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 
                                Dim Label36 As New Label 
                                If Not frm1.TextBox16.Text = TextBox8.Text Then 
                                    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 
                                    Dim Label38 As New Label 
                                    If Not frm1.TextBox18.Text = TextBox9.Text Then 
                                        lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 
                                        Dim Label40 As New Label 
                                        If Not frm1.TextBox20.Text = TextBox10.Text Then 
                                            lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1 
                                            frm4.Show() 
                                            Me.Hide() 
                                        Else 
                                            lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 1 
                                            frm4.Show() 
                                            Me.Hide() 
                                        End If 
                                    End If 
                                End If 
                            End If 
                        End If 
                    End If 
                End If 
            End If 
        End If 
    End If 

    If frm4 IsNot Nothing Then 
        frm4.Visible = False 
        frm4.Show(Me) 'Show Second Form 

        Me.Hide() 
    End If 
End Sub 


End Class
```

Comment: @ElektroStudios Hi sir it is okay that you criticize but just make it sure that it is in a constructive way and not foul :) helping instead of blaming will be better anyway.. by the way thanks for your input :)

Comment: Third time lucky? - triplicate of [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21668226/my-if-else-statement-vb-nets-weird-behavior?rq=1) AND [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21674258/statements-not-doing-its-function-vb-net?rq=1) - either that or three separate users with the same question!

Comment: @OSKM dont be so rude man I am asking in a polite way..my first thread  did not have the answer so its just right to make a way on how to get a help.. Thanks by the way for your concern.

Comment: Apologies - not intended to be rude just drawing attention to the other two questions to save some poor person wasting their valuable time repeating a suggestion already made, I almost did this on your second post before the link to the first was added! As a suggestion you would have been better to keep the same username and highlighted the previous questions within the new question mentioning why their answers were inadequate.

Comment: One point - whats the purpose of all the `Dim`-ed labels - they don't appear to be being used in the code sample - are they used elsewhere?

Comment: @OSKM its alright..I have used another account because my main account  has reached the limit of asking questions. The dim is used to declare the other forms to be called on the current form and its label. Do you have a solution to my problem? please if you have tell me Thanks again.

Comment: so where is  `Dim Label22 As New Label` for example added to the forms controls?

Comment: @OSKM i just forgot to omit it sir it does nothing. I am currently trying your solution right now sir. Thanks again for your time and effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time you add anything to `Lbl3` is:

```
If Not frm1.TextBox20.Text = TextBox10.Text Then 
    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1 
    frm4.Show() 
    Me.Hide() 
Else 
    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 1 
    frm4.Show() 
    Me.Hide() 
End If
```

With the nesting you have it is only if all the other If statements = True that you even get to this point.

In addition to this on ALL the other if statement your outcome is either `lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0` (if this statement and all previous ones were true) or if any of them are false ALL subsequent ones are irrelevant.

If i understand your intention correctly then what you want is instead of:

```
If frm1.TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text Then 
    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 'if(integer.tryparse, lbl3) then lbl3 += 1 
    Dim Label24 As New Label 
    If Not frm1.TextBox4.Text = TextBox2.Text Then 
        lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0
```

Try:

```
If frm1.TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text Then lbl3 += 1
If Not frm1.TextBox4.Text = TextBox2.Text Then lbl3 += 1
```

And so on....

Then to display it you need to update the following code:

```
If Not frm1.TextBox20.Text = TextBox10.Text Then 
    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 0 'frm4.Label3.Text = (frm4.Label3.Text) + 1 
    frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)
    frm4.Show() 
    Me.Hide() 
Else 
    lbl3 = CInt(lbl3) + 1
    frm4.Label3.Text = CStr(lbl3)
    frm4.Show() 
    Me.Hide() 
End If
```

(this is very similar to one of the answers on one of the other questions hence my comment above)

Comment: Hi sir thanks for the answer. It shows an error on this line frm4.Label3.Text = lbl3 The error is Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Integer' to 'String'.

Comment: problem solved sir! Thanks a lot I am taking back what I have said awhile ago that you are rude now i know that you are a nice person :) Thanks again many many thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Add setting code.

```
frm4.Label3.Text = lbl3.ToString()
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..Hi sir what do you mean can you please elaborate it? Thanks again

Comment: Your code doesn't save incremented value, so it shows always `0`.

Comment: hi sir where will i put the frm4.Label3.Text = lbl3.ToString()? Thanks

Comment: The thing you can't understand where it should be putted indicates you are not understanding your own code. So the problem is not code, its you.